# Highcharts with more than a thousand mySQL points

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts

I am using highcharts to display data from mySQL, but i can only print some data. I found out that this is because i need to use setExtremes. Can someone please help me so that I change my code ijn order to dispplay all my data?
Any help would be appreciated!

My working code (but shows only some data):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" / >
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="150">
<title>Fukt/Temp/Tryck</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
chart: {
zoomType: 'xy',
alignTicks: false,
renderTo: 'container',
type: 'line',
marginRight: 80,
marginBottom: 55
},
title: {
text: 'Temp och Fukt',
x: -20 //center
},
xAxis: {
crosshair: true,
type: 'datetime',
tickInterval: 80,
labels: {
format: '{value: %H:%M}',
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
day: '%H:%M'
}
}
},
yAxis: [{
title: {
tickInterval: 0.1,
text: '°C/%',
rotation: 0,
},
labels: {
overflow: 'justify'
}
},
{
title: {
tickInterval: 0.1,
text: '°C/%',
rotation: 0,
},
linkedTo:0,
opposite:true
}],
tooltip: {
shared: true
},
legend: {
enabled: true,
layout: 'horizontal',
align: 'center',
verticalAlign: 'bottom',
borderWidth: 0
},
series: []
}
$.getJSON("datatemphumi.php", function(json) {
options.xAxis.categories = json[3]['data'];
options.series[0] = json[1];
options.series[1] = json[2];
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0  
auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I get from datatemphumi.php: https://pastebin.com/bunAhzXV

And the example code that I want to achieve: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts/

Comment: Do you actually have problems with the data you provided? I made this fiddle with your chart options https://jsfiddle.net/peterlgh7/46nf7rq5/ and it seems to me like all data is there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I checked there are more categories than actual points. Categories without points will not be displayed, unless you force them to. You can for example use `max` property or mentioned by you previously, `setExtremes` function.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis.html#setExtremes

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nzoy4sqe/ - using `max`

Comment: Hi there, can you send me an example on how to show different categories that have different intervals using set extremes? I need them to be shown in one chart like in your examples...
But i need to show points in different timestampls for each category (as the values are not written at the same time for each categoy)

so my datatemphumi.php gives: https://pastebin.com/CcMMufVG

and my code is: https://pastebin.com/KR9Gbxfj

But its not working as expected. I need to be able to show the points like in this example: https://pasteboard.co/GT8vM8I.png